# Remove stubborn drill press chuck

Tags: tools, drill, chuck

I have an old craftsman drill press.  Model #113.213090:

[image]

and I've noticed the chuck that I have with it really starts to slip off drill bits, even if I try to crank it tight.  So anyhow I went to replace the chuck.  The chuck on it has these markings on it:

[image]

Which some quick googling told me means it has a j33 taper.  So i went and bought this chuck for an upgrade:

[image]

So now the trick is to get the old chuck off.  Youtube videos tell me its often either a removal key or you sometimes just kinda whack it with a mallet.  Per the manual for the drill, I think its the whack option:

[image]

**Heres where I'm stuck:**

A couple taps on each side with a mallet after opening the jaws as wide as they go and nothing is happening at all.  Sure, I could whack a little harder (to the point where the whole machine would wobble) but I dont want to do any damage.  Are there any tricks I dont know about?  Also, do I have a compatible upgrade chuck like I think I do?

**Update**:

After enough ‘whacking’ (listening to the manual and comments), this whole thing fell out:

[image]

But now I have no idea how to separate that spindle (is that what it is?) from the chuck in order to attach the replacement:
[image]

Comment: The older it is the more taps it probably needs.  It might even need good wacks before it lets go.

Comment: If you are going to hit it harder, you could consider holding a piece of scrap wood against the chuck and hitting that.  It can be hard to reliably hit something little like a chuck; at least for me.

Comment: I was using a piece of scrap wood already.  Tomorrow morning I’ll get a little harder with the taps and report back

Comment: @crip659  well, update above but still stuck

Comment: Check the inside of the chuck to make sure it does not have a screw holding it.  At least now you have more space for tapping.

Comment: @crip659 I’d see that screw from the bottom correct? I.e. where drill bit goes in? If so, I definitely don’t see any. Is the chuck just supposed to kind of “hang” on the spindle?

Comment: If no screw then it hangs, but it is a taper fiction fit so is on quite tight.  Usually to put them on recommended to give a couple of taps instead of just pushing them on.